# ACCESS Link data from one table to a second table

Tags: ms-access-2010

Using Access I need to pull the field from one table based on the entry in a field in the current record

```
Table 1:   dbo_STR
STR_NBR
STR_ST
```

and

```
Table 2: Store_Specific
STR_NBR
State
```

I need State in table 2 to pull from table 1 based on STR_NBR

ie

```
table 1   
1123    IL   
1124    NY
```

And

```
Table 2 
1123  (would grab IL from table 1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're doing this.  You can either join them in a query, or update the field using an UPDATE statement.  Is this happening after an specific event?

Table 2 can be updated with something like this:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Store_Specific "
strSQL = strSQL & "SET State = (SELECT STR_ST FROM dbo_STR WHERE STR_NBR = '" & MyNumber & "'") "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE STR_NBR = '" & MyNumber & "'"

DoCmd.Execute strSQL
```

It's a little bit of "aircode", but it should put you in the right direction.

Comment: I need this to happen when entering a new record in table 2 or Set it up to run on-demand.     I have a VBA module setup to run multiple SQL statements whenever i need to make bulk changes to the database.  I use the below VBA  Sub SqlScripts()

   Dim vSql     As Variant
   Dim vSqls    As Variant
   Dim strSql     As String
   Dim intF       As Integer
   intF = FreeFile()
   Open "c:\temp\dog.txt" For Input As #intF
   strSql = Input(LOF(intF), #intF)
   Close intF
   vSql = Split(strSql, ";")
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each vSqls In vSql
      CurrentDb.Execute vSqls
   Next
End Sub